# Converting HTML5 template to meteor.js, questions about JS init

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I'm converting a template to meteor.js, and got stuck with initializing JS. Please bear in mind I am a newbie wannabe programmer.

Using iron:router I split the page to different templates, my home page looks like this:

```
Router.map(function(){
this.route('home', {
  path: '/',
  layoutTemplate: 'fullLayout',
  yieldTemplates: {
    'menu': {to: 'menu'},
    'sidebar': {to: 'sidebar'},
    'footer': {to: 'footer'}
  }
});
```

The original HTML template inits some scripts at the end of each html file:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
   Core.init(); // init core componets
   Layout.init(); // init layout
   Page.init(); // this may be different / non-needed for different pages
});
</script>
```

Where shall I put this script, or how should I call these?
Any best practices? Maybe I shouldn't use jQuery(document).ready?
Thanks a lot for the help.

PS: Obviously manually I can init them from console, or by putting them at the end of each template, but there needs to be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In meteor execute ready function by onRendered. [Here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) the full documentation

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered({
   Core.init(); // init core componets
   Layout.init(); // init layout
   Page.init(); // this may be different / non-needed for different pages
});
```

Comment: Added the common functions to the fullLayout.onRendered, and the page-specific functions to the pages. Works like a charm, thank you.